# how do you integrate gamification with sharepoint

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010, integration

I am planning to use open source gamification - rails based Gioco gem to for enteprise productivity  and collaboration applications. I am starting with Sharepoint. While I have supporting material for gamification strategies and use of commercial software apps such as Badgeville, how can I integrate using REST/JSON API with Sharepoint?

Ideally I am looking to generate points on the gamification when users tag, upload, comment on Sharepoint and Yammer. So user action should trigger the REST API.

Comment: if you can afford to pay, use vendors like Badgeville, Bunchball etc, otherwise 
I would suggest to follow some wesbites with gamifications implementations then add the similar features in your site, 
http://blogs.clicksoftware.com/clickipedia/top-25-best-examples-of-gamification-in-business/
Gamification has many things(PBLs), you have to manage that too with points 
http://www.sitepoint.com/building-engaging-web-apps-game-mechanics/

Answer (score 2):

RedCritter has pre-built integration with SP2013 which is very easy to deploy. There are also pre-built integrations for workflow management tools like Nintex to reward granular behaviors within SharePoint.

https://redcritterconnecter.com/solutions

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be tough. There are *far too many* places in SharePoint you'd have to handle. While SharePoint does have various event handlers which you can hook up to trigger your code, they would have to be installed farm-wide in all sites, all lists and document libraries, independently. Then you would have to somehow hook up various web parts.

Alternate strategies:

- try to handle everything client-side in JavaScript — tedious in nature, error-prone, can't catch everything (e.g. Office integration beyond reach)
- turn on auditing everywhere and generate info from audit logs — will be behind in time in respect to user actions, won't catch everything again (e.g. various user interface operations that don't trigger audit records)

In any case, **your SharePoint farm admin won't fall in love with this**. Most likely you will cause them *a lot* of troubles and headaches, not speaking about unwanted interferences with 3rd party solutions deployed on the farm.

**My recommendation: don't waste your time, it's not worth it.**

Comment: Ondrej, Are you suggesting that Gamification for sharepoint is too hard to implement irrespective through opensource or commercial gamification platforms?

Comment: Exactly that's what I'm suggesting. The benefit in contrast to complications is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree with Ondrej - SharePoint is fully of proprietary functionality that will be a challenge to work with. I know you had your heart set on going open source, but I know that Badgeville specifically has a SharePoint connector which might get you what you need.

- http://badgeville.com/products/integration-catalog/badgeville-for-sharepoint